# How can I contact the owner of a patent?

Tags: patent-services

I am looking to contact a person who patented something. I am really interested in the vehicle covering system patent (US8430444) and would like to contact the inventor. Is there any way to get their contact information?

Comment: The title asks for the owner but the body of the question asks for the inventor. These are not necessarily the same person.

Answer (score 14):

I'm answering this question as a **general** guide on how to access contact information for patents that have issued, and applications that have published. Following these steps you can find the contact information on record.

1. Go to Public Pair: http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair
2. Input the Patent Number, Publication Number, or Application Number. You probably won't be searching by PCT Number or Control Number.
3. Now you can click on the tab that says "Address and Attorney/Agent." This will give you the contact information for the Attorney or Agent that prosecuted the case before the USPTO. Or, you can go to the "Image File Wrapper" tab and look for the document entitled "Oath or Declaration filed." There you should find the inventor's name and address. In this case it is on the third page of the document. Alternatively, under the "Image File Wrapper" you could search for the "Application Data Sheet," and the inventor name and address is on the first page.

Answer (score 6):

The question was about the OWNER of the patent. The answer explained how to contact the INVENTOR of the patent. Owner is not necessarily the Inventor.

The first step in determining the current ownership of any issued patent is to search the PTO assignment database, currently available at http://assignment.uspto.gov/
You can search by patent number.

This will not give you any contact information for the owner but I'm sure you can find any number of articles on the web about how to locate a person.

Comment: thanks for your comment and observation, question body mention to contact inventor.

Answer (score 2):

My searches produced:

Carl West - 905 Reynolds Dr, Sheridan, AR 72150 USA (870) 673-8125

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that can sometimes work is to take the full name of the inventor and place of residence and search them in Google. Also check in Espacenet to see if there are other patents or applications in other countries. You may well find a company listed there if the inventor was an employee. (yes I know this relates to the inventor, not owner, but it has been linked to from a question re inventor)