# How to find manufacturer of patented product

Tags: findmanufacturer, inventor

I am in search of finding the manufacturer of a patented product. I have found a supplier of the product, but the price they want to charge is quite high.

I have a sample of the product from the supplier I mentioned above, along with the patent number. I have searched the inventors, but am unable to find any contact info.

I contacted the lawyers that were involved in a recent patent with one of the inventors, but have not heard anything back.

Is there any other way to either find a manufacturer that creates the product, or contact info for the inventors?

Comment: The best bet you have is the Public Pair system at the USPTO: http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair start with the patent number and a phone book or online searching for the actual contact.  You may be able to find the lawyer easier than the actual inventor, but they may not disclose any information to you.  I once found an inventor who was retired for over 20 years and dug up his phone number through an old advertisement he made. I was shocked when I got him on the phone and we had a wonderful conversation about his patents that were expired and re-patented by someone else. Fun times.

Comment: @TylerUlrich So far I have attempted to contact 4 attorneys the inventor has worked with, and haven't heard from any of them. I found a phone number for the inventor online today. I'm going to call, and see if it is still the inventors current number. Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I contact the owner of a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent)