# How can I contact the inventor or applicant of a European patent or application?

Tags: copyright, inventor, ep1870511a1, european, applicant

I'm interested in contacting the owner of [EP1870511A1](http://www.google.com/patents/EP1870511A1?cl=from). Where can I find information to do so?

I've reviewed "[How can I contact the owner of a patent?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent)," but it appears to only cover American patents and applications.

Answer (score 1):

To get in touch with the inventor or applicant of a European patent or application you need to accesses the European patent register.

http://www.epo.org/searching/free/register.html

After which open the EP register and click on advanced search https://register.epo.org/advancedSearch?lng=en

Enter EP1870511 in the publication number bracket and you’ll get the results.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

To find out EP applicant or inventor or representative communication details you need to visit EP Register.

1. search european patent in http://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP
2. access EP register tab on biblographic page

steps are compiled in following image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The application you mention is not a French national application, but a European patent application. The applicant's contact information is available through EPregister:

https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP06012952

Also note that the patent was granted with publication number EP 1870511 B1.