# Patent enquiry for Eco friendly products

Tags: assignee

My application requested for an existing U.S. patent was filed,
 I received a copy personally signed by a certifying officer in the mail.
Does this mean I have been granted the use of this patent. Or is it just a basic copy of the patent.
 I am starting up a recycling plant and am in desperate need of this specific patent in order to export the End Use waste capturing products and to prevent added waste into landfill sites.
Please guide me so I can accelerate to commercialisation 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ordering a certified copy of a patent from the patent office does not grant the right to practice the invention. It is simply a copy. Certified copies are commonly used when filing in a different country or when the patent is required in court.

In order to practice the invention, you need to either own the patent or have permission from the owner. Purchasing a patent may be prohibitively expensive, or simply not possible.  The the more likely course of action is to negotiate a license.

In either case, you will need to contact the owner of the patent. See [How can I contact the owner of a patent?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/5351/9802)