# How can I upload a PDF to Google patents?

Tags: us20130240651

In reference to the patent: [US20130240651](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130240651)

How can I upload a PDF to Google patents?

Comment: Hi user13335, could you please [edit] your post to clarify how it relates to patents as defined in our [help/on-topic]? Questions about the use of tools like Google Patents *are* accepted here, but I'm not sure I see what you mean by "upload the...pdf to Google." Google Patents is sourced from patent documents, as far as I know. You aren't going to be able to upload anything to it. Maybe you're looking to [contact the patent's owner](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059)?

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question to better-fit what *I thought* you were asking. I also took the liberty of removing the link, since I didn't see the relevance of it. Please [edit] your post further if I was incorrect in my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

there are no option for uploading pdf document in said section. Patent application can be downloaded using google patents.
please further clarify your question.