# Does anybody have any information about the inventor Manuel Guillen?

Tags: inventor, inventor-declaration

In reference to the patent: [US6074673](https://www.google.com/patents/US6074673)

I wanted to have Informations about the inventor of the patent and if it is possible to contact him.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer for contacting patent owners can be found [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent).

In this case, the image file wrapper is not available electronically.  If you wanted a physical copy of the application data sheet with the inventors address when the application was filed, you could order a copy of the file wrapper from the USPTO or another provider for a fee.

Alternatively, a [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=manuel+guillen+fairfax+va) of the inventors name and city listed on the patent may point you in the right direction.