# How do I contact the owner of a WIPO applications?

Tags: websites, public, knowledge

In reference to the patent: [WO2013093909A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013093909A1)

I would like to get in contact with the Company or Hama Energy Ltd. or its owner.

I have read [How can I contact the owner of a patent?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent), but it applies only to United States patents.

Answer (score 1):

For WIPO application Contact Details-

1. Go to Patent Scope (WIPO Search interface) https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf
2. Input publication number details
3. open respective patent application
4. Go to Documents Tab and download Declaration; It will contain contact details

e.g.
[image]