# How to Find current Ownership of a patent?

Tags: ownership, assignment

In reference to the patent: [USD259587](https://www.google.com/patents/USD259587)

Ways to figure out the current legal ownership status of patent?

Comment: **Related:** [How do I contact the owner of a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059)

Comment: I'm not sure whether I consider this a duplicate of that or not, but in any event, it should have your answer, as I understand your question.

Comment: Does it matter? I would think the patent would have expired by now.

Answer (score 2):

Patents are rights which can be transferred from one entity to another. After assignment of such rights its important to notify patent office about such assignments. for US Patent these assignments are listed in [Assignment database](http://assignment.uspto.gov/). you are recommended to read help on [how to search](http://assignment.uspto.gov/#/about)

Another way to find such information is to look into [PUBLIC PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) assignment Tab.

1. Go to Public Pair: http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair
2. Input the Patent Number, Publication Number, or Application Number. You probably won't be searching by PCT Number or Control Number.

for example this patent application PAIR

[image]

DRAWBACK:- Sometime reporting of assignment is not done then such changes wont be listed in database. In such case your best bet will be News or paid databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Publication number  USD259587 S
Publication type    Grant
Application number  US 06/001,968
Publication date    Jun 16, 1981
Filing date Jan 8, 1979
Inventors   Philip E. Jergenson
Original Assignee   Proto Plant Inc.
Export Citation BiBTeX, EndNote, RefMan
```

This patent is long expired.  It is a design patent, which are only valid for 14 years, and it issued in 1981.

It was owned by Proto Plant, Inc. as can be seen at the link at Google Patents.