# Who owns this patent at this point of time?

Tags: ownership, us20120221930, motor

In reference to the patent: [US194047](https://www.google.com/patents/US194047)

Who Owns this Patent now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find current Ownership of a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12323/11895) Also check [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895)

Comment: FYI patent expired long back