# Where can I find the contact details of the inventors of EP2546383A1?

Tags: meta-data, us20120321478

I would like to receive the contact details of the inventors of [EP2546383A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2546383A1) and I would like to know information related to material used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I contact the owner of a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent)

Answer (score 1):

Just to test the [instructions for finding contact information for inventors](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/5351/14622), I went through the steps and found that searching on [US 2012/0321478](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120321478) led to the appropriate contact information, which is Hitachi, Ltd. IP Group:

```
c/o Hitachi, Ltd., Intellectual Property Group
12th Floor, Marunouchi Center Building, 6-1
Marunouchi 1-chrome, Chiyoda-ku, Tokyo
100-8220, Japan
```

In this case, it would be inappropriate to contact the inventors directly, as they would likely need to vet any information through this group anyway.