# Inventor contact

Tags: us20080083719

In reference to the patent: [US20080083719](https://www.google.com/patents/US20080083719)

Dear!

```
 Please tell me how can i get inventor contact for this patent.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) you can find that the inventor is identified as "John J. Bartucco , Meeker, CO (US)".

Here is a corresponding [whitepages search result](http://www.whitepages.com/name/John-J-Bartucco/Meeker-CO) and [google results](http://bit.ly/1UQKUqe).

Please also see earlier [question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent) indicated by [Pushpack](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/11895/pushpak).

More over, not sure it is worth trying to buy it... [USPTO](http://www.uspto.gov/) [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) indicates that its status is "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action". In Final Rejection examiner indicates that the content of the patent application is unpatentable over [CA2164917](http://www.google.com/patents/CA2164917A1?cl=en) in view of [US4456947](http://www.google.com/patents/US4456947) - there is not enough novelty.

Comment: Is this patent currently being used or is it for sale ?

Comment: See updated answer.