# In reference to the patent: [WO2014007762A1]

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [WO2014007762A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014007762A1)

Hi,

I came across an idea which is similar to this patent and during my search found it's already been patented. I do have a few questions (namely the inventor) and hope I can get some answers.

1. This invention/idea, has it already been implemented or is it in the process of doing so?
2. If not yet what are the hurdles faced?
3. I firmly believe it is a very good idea and if the inventor is interested he can contact me so we can share ideas.

Thanks,
Don.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have a direct channel to the patent holder so they will not get your message here. For contact information see **[How can I contact the owner of a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059)**