# How to determine the status of a patent application on Google Patents?

Tags: patent-applications, patent-search, status

In reference to the patent: [USD708869](https://www.google.com/patents/USD708869)

How Do I check if this patent been approved? Why or why not? When? Is the patent owner still alive? Is the patent for sale? Are there other similar patents?

Answer (score 2):

The link in your question *is* the granted patent.

You can see on the box at the right of the Google Patents page that its Publication Type is "Grant," meaning it's a patent and no longer an application, and that its Publication date was July 15, 2014.

[image: Status box from Google Patents]

Unfortunately, I can't speak to the licensing that its assignee has in place, if any, and I don't know whether they're still alive (although having filed this in 2014, it wouldn't surprise me).

I would suggest checking out [How can I contact the owner of a patent?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/5059/10011) for information about finding the owner. Contacting them would be your best bet to work out a licensing arrangement.