# Who is the inventor of this patent?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US20060218693](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060218693)

I would like to inquire who owns this patent and if they are selling it ?

Answer (score 1):

Answers to [this question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent) address how to contact the inventors of a US patent or patent application (essentially, by looking up the case in Public PAIR and finding the inventor contact information in the Application Data Sheet).

The inventors of a patent application are not necessarily the owner ("assignee"). However, in this case, it appears that the sole inventor (Andres Sinohui) is indeed the original assignee. That said, it is possible that the application has been assigned to someone else at a later date. You can use [this tool](https://assignment.uspto.gov/patent/index.html) to see if any new assignments have been registered with the USPTO.

Also, keep in mind that this is not a patent, but just an application. It may never issue as a patent, and if it does, the claims (which define the invention protected by the patent) may be significantly different from those shown in the application.